# Уведомление о новом сообщении

Tags: objective-c, ios

Разрабатываю клиент для соцсетей, вопрос в том, как сделать уведомление о появившемся новом сообщении? С АПИ соцсетей общаюсь не напрямую, через свой сервер. Собственно и вопрос, как он меня может уведомить о полученном новом сообщении? Через push? плюсы, минусы, другие варианты?

Comment: через пуш. очень хороший вариант.

Можно на email слать или смской. Плюсы-минусы очевидны.

Есть и другие варианты (сервис написать), но к счастью не на айоси.

Comment: Я имеюю ввиду оповещение не только, когда приложение закрыто или свернуто, а и в активном режиме. Надо ж мне как то узнать, что появилось сообщение. Не опрашивать же мне сервер через каждых там 10 сек. (как вариант можно использовать сокеты) Я тоже рассматриваю пуш. Просто хочу удостовериться, верный ли это выбор для данной задачи?

Comment: пуш не то что верный, а рекомендуемый.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только если использовать пуш или написать лонгполл на своем сервере. Например, у vk.com есть longpoll connection и прекрасно работает, быстрее пуша. Вот описание такого сервиса в API vc.com, можно написать свой подобный этому: https://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=Подключение_к_LongPoll_серверу

у меня есть опыт реализации такого подхода - работает отлично, вопреки всем ожиданиям батарею дико не кушает